# How to ignore - ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def isAlreadyInstalled(lookupRegistryKey):
    consoleLines = os.popen('reg query "' + APP_REGISTRY_KEY + "\\" + VERSION_SYSTEM_NAME + '"').readlines()
    if len(consoleLines) == 0:
        return False
    return True
```

So i've created this method but the problem is, when i execute my script, in the command line I get this error:

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

I have not managed to ignore it. How can I ignore this error that shows up in the command line during the execution ?

Comment: I want to simply ignore it . I don't want to see it showing in the cmd line

Comment: Pipe `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to nothing or internal buffers and it won't show up on your Python's `STDOUT`/`STDERR`. Here's [one example](https://gist.github.com/ajdavis/6222554).

Comment: And what do you expect the function to return if it cannot find the directory?\

Comment: The thing is that I call this method evrey second,for 5 mins while I'm the script executes an installer. So this is meant to search this key to see if the installer is executing. So basically I just don't need see this in my cmd because anyway if the key is not found in 5 minutes my loop will stop calling this method.

Comment: If you want to consult the registry, don't use `os.popen()`, or the `subprocess` module either. Look at the standard library module `winreg`.

Comment: @BoarGules would winreg.QueryInfoKey(APP_REGISTRY_KEY) be enough in this case?

Comment: I would normally do a simple presence check by calling `OpenKeyEx()` and trapping for `OSError`. `QueryInfoKey()` gets metadata like number of subkeys.

Answer (score 0):

So you want this function to return `True` or `False` based on `if len(consoleLines) == 0:` or else just return the control back, that can be done as

```
def isAlreadyInstalled(lookupRegistryKey):
    try:
        consoleLines = os.popen('reg query "' + APP_REGISTRY_KEY + "\\" + VERSION_SYSTEM_NAME + '"').readlines()
        if len(consoleLines) == 0:
            return False
        return True
    except: 
        return
```

Comment: This still pops the message in cmd for me

Comment: Does the execution also stop after that?

Comment: If the execution stops then the problem is somewhere else in your code, if the execution does not stop, while running your code use `python yourScriptName.py 2> /dev/null`

Comment: The script does not stop.But is it possible to add those parameters somewhere in the script to ignore those messagges?

Comment: `import sys` `sys.stderr = DevNull()` is a method, but I have not used it before so I cannot gaurantee.